# Ping issue on new Debian 9 VM

Tags: debian, ping

I can ping my gateway, but nothing else.
I can ping the Linux VM from my workstation and a server and get a response. This is both for pinging the actual IP address and the domain name.

Thoughts? I tried looking for some information on it, but everything appears to be more no ping at all that I have found online.

Ping on Linux VM:

```
root@Server:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5122ms

root@Server:/# traceroute google.ca
traceroute to google.ca (172.217.3.163), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  206.116.239.129 (206.116.239.129)  0.345 ms  0.292 ms  0.375 ms
 2  208.181.248.85 (208.181.248.85)  2.166 ms  2.846 ms  2.524 ms
 3  154.11.10.11 (154.11.10.11)  6.438 ms  6.431 ms ae0.100.STTLWAWBGR80.bb.telus.com (154.11.10.9)  7.679 ms
 4  72.14.220.60 (72.14.220.60)  6.308 ms  6.412 ms  6.298 ms
 5  108.170.245.113 (108.170.245.113)  9.440 ms  9.573 ms  8.020 ms
 6  108.170.233.159 (108.170.233.159)  9.590 ms  9.387 ms 108.170.233.157 (108.170.233.157)  7.585 ms
 7  sea15s11-in-f3.1e100.net (172.217.3.163)  7.566 ms  7.565 ms  7.653 ms

root@Server:/# ping google.ca
PING google.ca (172.217.3.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.ca ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3064ms
```

Ping works going to the Linux VM.

During set up and install, I have been able to access the internet to download and install packages without issues.

Newer to Linux, so I'm still trying to chase everything down.

Also, forgot to add the other ping info:

```
root@Server:/# ping 192.168.xxx.1
PING 192.168.xxx.1 (192.168.xxx.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.xxx.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.xxx.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.xxx.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
^C
--- 192.168.xxx.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2024ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.112/0.134/0.146/0.020 ms

root@Server:/# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.x.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
192.168.x.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
192.168.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
```

Comment: what hypervisor do you use? and how you configure vm network (bridge-utils?)?

Comment: I'm using the vSphere Client connected to ESXi. Both version 6

The network is configured through DHCP, with address reservations. So once we add a reservation into the system, when the VM grabs an IP, the MAC is scanned, and the appropriate IP is provided.

Comment: What is the device 192.168.x.1? Does it have any form of firewall? Is it performing NAT or just straightforward routing? (If just routing, then please apply all these questions to every box until your upstream NAT device.) Could it be blocking ICMP ping probes (or the responses) but not blocking HTTP on tcp/80 & tcp/443?

Comment: I ran through the settings again to verify, and for whatever reason, there was a change done over the weekend that caused the subnet the server was on to become restricted to ping. Adjusted the settings and we have ping now.

Answer (score 1):

The subnet had been adjusted to refuse ping for some reason. Corrected the issue, and issue resolved now.

Answer (score -1):

> I can ping my gateway, but nothing else.

#### I assumed your VM can ping it's gateway of 192.168.x.1, but cannot ping anything outside such as google.com or 8.8.8.8 (google dns ).

#### Solution:

*On your server*

**To let your VM see the outside, do this from the server**

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

*This assumes your interface is named eth0, alternatively you may simply do*

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j MASQUERADE
```

This will work as well.

### Let us know if this solved the problem.

Comment: It can clearly see the outside because the OP wrote, "_During set up and install, I have been able to access the internet to download and install packages without issues_".

Comment: Check the firewall, iptables or rules to ensure that you are not blocking pinging at all.